# If $(x^2-5x+4)(y^2+y+1)<2y$ for all real values of $y$ then what interval does $x$ belong to?

Tags: quadratics, quadratic-forms

Okay so I'm stuck on this one for a long time :

> If $(x^2-5x+4)(y^2+y+1)<2y$ for all real values of $y$ then what interval does $x$ belong to?

**My Try:** Since $y$ can take any real value, I tried multiplying the first two terms and formed a quadratic equation in $y$ with its coefficients and the constant term in terms of $x$. Then I applied the two conditions as:

1. Coefficient of $y^2$ should be negative ; and
2. Discrimnant should also be negative.

Am I correct? What am I doing wrong? Is there a better approach to solve similar problems like this one? Please let me know.

Comment: Can $y^2+y+1$ ever be negative? If not, then dividing by it puts all the $y$ parts on the right hand side and keeps it a less-than inequality. Then see what values that right hand side can take.

Comment: Understood what you're trying to say, but how is that exactly going to help? It still remains an inequality since I don't know what effect the term $2y$ in the numerator is going to have on the inequality.

Comment: Once you have all the $y$ parts on the right hand side, find the minimum value the right hand side can take. That is then the bound that is imposed on the the left hand side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

let $a = (x^2 - 5x + 4)$

For what values of $a$ is

$a(y^2 + y + 1)< 2y$?

$(ay^2 + (a-2) y + a)< 0$ for all $y$

$a<0$ and $(ay^2 + (a-2) y + a)$ has no real roots.

$(a-2)^2 - 4a^2 < 0\\
-3a^2 - 4a + 4 <0\\
-(3a -2)(a+2)<0$

$a<- 2$

$x^2 - 5x + 4 < - 2$

and solve for $x$

Comment: You probably know it, but let me just say it, you're a GENIUS!

Comment: I'm going to ask more problems all day today, please keep an eye and try to help if you can. I'll really appreciate your time and effort! Thanks.

Comment: @user38227 thanks, except I chunked up the easiest factorization in the problem.  Fixed now.

Comment: Trivial really, since you broke the problem into something really easy, it doesn't matter. Also, can I change my username here?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee $x = 4$ is not a solution $(4^2 - 5*4 + 4)(y^2 + y + 1) < 2y \implies 0<2y$ which is not true for all $y.$

Comment: @DougM Changed my upvote to a downvote, sorry! But I still don't really understand ... shouldn't $x=4$ be considered a solution because there exist some $y$ (e.g. $y=1$) that allow $x=4$?

Comment: Find an interval(s) for $x$ such that the inequality is true for all real $y$

Comment: @DougM I like that phrasing a lot better! I need to read more carefully :)

Comment: @user38227 click on your icon and reputation at the top of the screen, then click on Edit Profile and Settings.

Answer (score 5):

$$(x^2−5x+4)(y^2+y+1)<2y$$

$y^2+y+1$ is positive, because it is smallest at $y=-\frac{1}{2}$, and substituting that gives something positive.

Therefore we can divide by $y^2+y+1$ without changing the direction of the inequality.

$$x^2−5x+4<\frac{2y}{y^2+y+1}$$

We want this to be true for all values of $y$. In particular it has to be true when the$ \frac{2y}{y^2+y+1}$ is at its smallest, which is when it places the tightest restriction on the left hand side.

To minimise $\frac{2y}{y^2+y+1}$, you can look at where its derivative changes sign from negative to positive (which is at $y=-1$) or do the trick that DougM did in the other answer (setting it equal to $a$, and finding the smallest $a$ for which the quadratic in $y$ still has a solution). Either way, the minimal value is $-2$.

This gives:
$$x^2−5x+4<-2\\
(x-5/2)^2-25/4+4<-2\\
(x-5/2)^2<1/4\\
-1/2<x-5/2<1/2\\
2<x<3$$

Comment: Nicely done. +1

Answer (score 4):

First, notice that $y^2+y+1$ is **positive** for all real values of $y$.

This means that we can divide by $y^2+y+1$ on both sides of the inequality, without having to worry about negative values that would change the direction of the inequality.

---

Divide by $y^2+y+1$ on both sides:

$$x^2 -5x + 4 < \frac{2y}{y^2+y+1}$$

---

We can find the minima and maxima of the rational function of $y$ on the right hand side, by taking its derivative and setting it equal to zero:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}\left(\frac{2y}{y^2+y+1}\right) = 0$$

$$\frac{2-2y^2}{\left(y^2+y+1\right)^2}=0$$

Since the denominator is always positive, we can simply eliminate it and divide by $2$:

$$1-y^2 = 0$$

$$y=\pm 1$$

This means that $2y/\left(y^2+y+1\right)$ achieves a minimum value of $-2$ at $y=-1$, and achieves a maximum value of $2/3$ at $y=1$. Therefore,

$$-2 \leq \frac{2y}{y^2+y+1}\leq \frac{2}{3}$$

---

At the boundary values for the right hand side, the inequality becomes:

$$x^2 - 5x + 4 < -2\,\, \implies\,\, x^2 - 5x + 6 < 0$$

$$x^2 - 5x + 4 < \frac{2}{3}\,\, \implies\,\, x^2 -5x + \frac{10}{3} <0 $$

Here, the first inequality is a tighter bound for $x$ than the second inequality, so we may only consider the first:
$$x^2 - 5x + 6 < 0$$

Factoring gives:

$$(x-2)(x-3)<0$$

This is a concave-up parabola with zeroes at $x=2$ and $x=3$. This means that the range of values for which the quadratic is negative is exactly *between* the two roots:

$$\boxed{2 < x < 3\,}$$

Comment: Don't know what you did, but you got the wrong answer!

Comment: The value is $\frac{2}3$ at $y=1$.

Comment: By this methodology, $(x^2 -5x +4) < f(y)$ the minimal value of $f(y)  = -2$ your mistake lies in looking at the range of $f(y)$

Comment: @TakahiroWaki I corrected that now, thank you! I think I may have misinterpreted the question though, I'm not sure ...

Comment: Since $x^2-5x+4<-2$ satisfies both inequalities, the answer must be same with Doug M's.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki So I should be using $x^2-5x+4 < -2$ instead of $x^2 -5x + 4 < 2/3$? (for the last three steps)

Comment: Yes, it is. Then the answer is ....

Comment: @TakahiroWaki Finally I think it is fixed ... thank you for helping :)